# How can i animate the camera creating a short clip to move the camera from point to point slowly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: [Panning / Animating the Camera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSn0hnxpE2w)

The first problem i have is when he in the tutorial bring up the Animation window and select the Main Camera he have the Main Camera and it's transform already on the left window. In my case i need to click on Add Property and then i have window with Transform, Main Camera.....etc If i select the Transform i have there Position Rotation and Scale i can select and click on add:[image: Camera Anim]

Then i select one by one the Position Rotation and Scale and i'm clicking no the red recording button then moving the red line of the frames to be on 00. Then i click on Add keyframe then i move the red line to frame 5 for 5 seconds and then click on Add keyframe again but i don't see this yellow line like in the tutorial. 
[image: Camera Anim 2]

This is where i moved the red line to the frames after 5 seconds and after clicked Add keyframe again:
[image: Camera Anim 3]

Why i don't have this yellow line in the key frames window on the right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video, it looks like the instructor has the 'Curves' view selected to show how the values are changing.

Try pushing this button here: [image: Curve button location]